# How to block every image on a website?

Tags: browser, web, blocking

I would like to be able to block every image on websites that suffer from severe clickbaity images so only text is shown. It would be nice if the solution could be dis/enabled easily in case I would like to see the images temporarily. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### tl;dr

Just add one (or both) of these rules to your adblocker's filters:

- `example.com##img` to block every `<img>` element
- `example.com$image` to block every image served from `example.com`

Check the notes section for more.

### Tutorial

1. Install an adblocker (like [uBlock Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm)) and click on its icon.
   [image: uBlock Origin panel]
2. Click on the "My filters" bar and paste `example.com##img` and/or `example.com$image`.
   [image: uBlock Origin filters tab]
3. Click "Apply changes".

If you would like to temporarily disable the block, just click the large on/off button on the plugins panel as shown in the first image.

### Notes

- `example.com##img` blocks every `<img>` DOM nodes on the given website. It doesn't matter where the image is served from, if it is inside an `<img>` tag, it will be blocked, but it won't block images that are displayed with different techniques like using `background-image` on a `<div>`.
- `example.com$image` will block every image served from `example.com` no matter which site tries to load them. Many sites use a CDN to serve their pics like `examplecdn.com` so blocking images coming from `example.com` will have little to no effect, so you have to block `examplecdn.com` too, just be aware that images on other sites that use `examplecdn.com` will be blocked as well.
- Sometimes blocking doesn't happen because the images were cached. In this case you need to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to make a hard refresh without using the cache.
- Sometimes images have an identifiable class attribute on the DOM node. After a bit of inspecting with devtools (right click->Inspect Element) you can list the classes that mark most of the images and block them the class selector way: `example.com##.image-container`
- There is a [great cheatsheet on the filter syntax](https://adblockplus.org/en/filter-cheatsheet).

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me with the latest uBlock origin. But this does: `example.com$image`

Comment: @bmaupin I checked it and it works for me, however its effectiveness depends on the way the given site implements image displaying. I updated the answer to elaborate on this.